# Getting datas from Dictionaries in lists Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I've been thinking and reading for a while, but I haven't found a solution so far. My problem is, I have some dictionaries in a list

```
goodsandprices = [{'good': 'apple', 'price': 10}, {'good': 'pear', 'price': 20}, {'good': 'orange', 'price': 25}, {'good': 'plum', 'price': 15}, {'good': 'wine', 'ar': 40}]
```

I'm not even sure if it is correct, well my program didn't make a fuss about it. My intention is to collect every data which has "price" key, and get the minimum value of it. my first guess was like

```
min(goodsandprices['price']))
```

but this gave me an error. Could you give me a tip how to do this?

Comment: `min(i['price'] for i in goodsandprices)`

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the member with the smallest `price` value, you could do:

```
print min(goodsandprices, key=lambda _:_["price"])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `min(iterable, *[, key, default])` function with a callback function as `key` argument:

```
goodsandprices = [{'good': 'apple', 'price': 10}, {'good': 'pear', 'price': 20}, {'good': 'orange', 'price': 25}, {'good': 'plum', 'price': 15}, {'good': 'wine', 'ar': 40}]
result = min(goodsandprices, key=lambda x: getattr(x, 'price', 0))

print(result['price'])
```

The output:

```
10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
goodsandprices = [{'good': 'apple', 'price': 10}, {'good': 'pear', 'price': 20}, {'good': 'orange', 'price': 25}, {'good': 'plum', 'price': 15}, {'good': 'wine', 'ar': 40}]    
key = 'price'
arr1 = []

for item in goodsandprices:
    if key in item:
        arr1.append(item['price'])


print min(arr1)
```